# The effect of the voltage at the Downs cell

Tags: electrochemistry, electrolysis

I referred the Wikipedia and Advance Chemistry by Philip Matthews, for having a much comprehension on the down cell, but there was a opposition while reading the both references.

[Wikipedia states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downs_cell) that,

> Although theory predicts that a potential of a little over 4 volts
>   should be sufficient to cause the reaction to go forward, in practice
>   potentials of up to 8 volts are used. This is done in order to achieve
>   useful current densities in the electrolyte despite its inherent
>   electrical resistance. The overvoltage and consequent resistive
>   heating contributes to the heat required to keep the electrolyte in a
>   liquid state.

But the Advance Chemistry book by Philip Matthews (page 521) states that,

> A large current is passed through the cell, but at a low voltage.
>   This has the effect of both discharging the sodium effectively and
>   heating the mixture so that it does not crystallize

The both references have a opposition at the fact of amount of voltage to heat generating.

Which one is correct? Also I hope an answer with the reasons of how does the voltage affect on downs cell, with the heat generating.  Thanks

Comment: Matthews assertion of "low voltage" is non-specific. Some over voltage will be necessary. The exact amount of over voltage depends on a number of cell design features.